# Hyperledger Composer REST server wallet not unique

Tags: authentication, passport.js, hyperledger-composer

I have successfully completed [Christopher Ganga's tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/gangachris125/passport-jwt-authentication-for-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-jqfgkoljn) for using Passport-JWT authentication.  My problem is when I submit a second bearer token with a second username, it returns a second access code which connects me to the same wallet and Id Card I imported previously.  How do I get a separate wallet for each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, too. 
I found a solution below that tutorial and it works for me.
Hope my answer can help you.

---

In that tutorial, author said that
" Composer Rest Server also requires that the JWT token have a claim of either **id** or **username**. (Not sure why this is the case) "

He uses **username** in the claims and generates the JWToken. 
If you use only **id** in the claim, everything works out fine.

My claim is like below:

```
var claims = {
  id: "001",
  name: "alice"
}
```